# Get total size of attached files on all list items in SharePoint 2007with PowerShell v2.0

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2007

Using Powershell I have to get the total size of all attached files on all list items for a generic list. I tryed to use the function below but this will display the total length of names for the attached files.

```
function GetListSize($List, $Web)
{
    [long]$listSize = 0                 

    foreach ($listItem in $List.Items)
    {                   
        $listItemAttachments = $listItem.Attachments 
        foreach($file in $listItemAttachments) 
        {            
            $listSize +=  $file.Length 
        }
    }

    $totalInMb = ($listSize/1024)/1024
    $totalInMb = "{0:N2}" -f $totalInMb

    return $totalInMb    
}
```

I can do this using c# (http://mykiavash.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-size-of-sharepoint-2010-list-item-attachment/) code but no ideea using PowerShell script. Do you have any ideea ?

Comment: The above code is actually for getting the size of a list. `$file.length` gives the file "size" not the length of filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, omlin helped me to solve this. pls see :

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12652/get-total-size-of-attached-files-on-all-list-items-in-sharepoint-2007with-powersh

To check the size using the interface this is nice : http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2008/06/20/list-size-reporting.aspx